# Count characters and append mysql select

Tags: mysql, substring

I am using the following to only select the first 40 characters from a column

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(w.item_title,1,40) as title from tableName blah blah
```

What I really want to do though is:

If `w.item_title` is over 40 characters, return only the first 40 and append with ... else just return `w.item_title` as it is

Is this possible at `SELECT` stage and should it be done there? Or should it be processed after the fact?

I am using JS to display the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(INSERT(w.item_title, 41, 3, '...'), 1, 43)
  FROM ...
```

See the manual on the [INSERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) String function for examples.

> **INSERT(str,pos,len,newstr)**
>   Returns the string str, with the substring beginning at position pos
>   and len characters long replaced by the string newstr. Returns the
>   original string if pos is not within the length of the string.
>   Replaces the rest of the string from position pos if len is not within
>   the length of the rest of the string. Returns NULL if any argument is
>   NULL.

**EDIT**
Last parameter of `SUBSTR` should be `43` as pointed out by Joachim.

Comment: +1 Nifty :) The last parameter should be 43, not 44 though, and note that it will put `...` at the end of strings that are exactly 40 characters too which may (probably) be an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You're right ... so, Darren, this is not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

QUERY:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(w.item_title)>40
            THEN SUBSTRING(w.item_title,1,40)
            ELSE w.item_title END as title 
from tableName w
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an 'IF' to append your suffix;

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(w.item_title,1,40),
              IF(LENGTH(w.item_title)>40, '...', '')) as title 
FROM tableName w
```

[SQLfiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d24/1).

On whether it should be done in the database, that's a trickier question that can as always be answered with "it depends".

If your text is long (for example articles), it's rather clear cut that you don't want to transfer the whole article if you only need the first 40 characters, but if the texts are short, you may want to offload the calculation from the database. It's easy to add web servers, but scaling the database up is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `Left`

```
SELECT CONCAT(Left(w.item_title,40),
              IF(LENGTH(w.item_title)>40, 'something', '')) as title 
FROM tableName w
;
```

Another:

```
SELECT case when Length(w.item_title) > 40 then 
       Left(w.item_title,40) else
       CONCAT(coalesce(w.item_title,''), 'something') End as title 
FROM tableName w
;
```

Comment: @DarrenSweeney please take a look at this. And guess what [Left is faster than Substr](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,265979,266043#msg-266043).. :) You may check your `explian` plan to confirm as well.